# Can my neighbour on the same router allow for access/hackability to my pc by opening a virus or somewhat

Tags: router, security

My mates accounts getting hacked and so are his bank accounts. What is going on and how can we catch these children.

Comment: It wpuld be easier to help if you probided more context for your question, but my first question would be why anyone who is not directly in your family and trusted unconditionally is on your "router" or network. Of you have a wireless network, type in your routers IP (find online or in manual - often 192.168.0.1 or 10.0.0.1) and configure *WPA*, which requires that you enter a password to connect.

Comment: This question is _extremely_ ambiguous. There is no way anybody here can help you with your specific problems unless you give proper context of what is going on. For example, does the router have a secure WPA2 connection (**NOT WEP**)? Does the website have a secure HTTPS connection? Is there any unusual clients connected to the router? Even with some context, this problem is very general and can have many causes. Although client isolation, as the first answer suggested, and other methods of securing your network may help, nobody here has any idea of your specific situation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're intentionally sharing your router with your neighbor in order to share internet (which I'd advise against anyway), and assuming they're accessing it wirelessly, it should be safe to enable settings on your router that prevent the various computers on the network from seeing each other.  (Of course this prevents your PC's from being able to see each other as well)

Generally this settings is called `WiFi Isolation`, `AP Isolation`, or `Client Isolation`.  Where you find this in your router settings will depend on the model.

If you're not intentionally sharing your router with them, then you need to properly secure your router with a good admin password (change it), WPA2, and a good WPA2 passphrase.

As for how to catch them, that's a lot harder.  Or maybe even impossible.  They could just be sniffing traffic rather than actually hacking into your system.  In that case there's nothing to "detect" on your systems or equipment.  You'd have to actually view logs and files on **their** systems.

Furthermore, it's not necessarily your neighbors doing the hacking. If your mate uses poor security on their passwords on the internet (same password everywhere) then all their accounts could easily be compromised without anyone being on your network at all.

For example, Yahoo was hacked recently.  If they use the same password for Yahoo and their bank, then the hacker could easily get their password from the Yahoo hack and in combination with their yahoo email address they could easily access everything else they've used that password on or associated that email address with.